# Android 2.2 cutting off MediaPlayer sound playback?

Tags: android, media-player, android-2.2-froyo

After some Googling it appears this is a common problem but I have yet to find an actual solution. I haven't tested on an actual device, but the emulator is cutting off my sound clips at around 80% done. I am playing back .wav files.

Does anyone know a programmatic solution to these problems?

edit:

```
    public void play(Context context){
    if (soundPlayer != null){
        soundPlayer.release();
    }

    int rId = 0;

    switch(aIndex){
        case 0: rId = R.raw.c0; break;
        case 1: rId = R.raw.c1; break;
        case 2: rId = R.raw.c2; break;
        case 3: rId = R.raw.c3; break;
        case 4: rId = R.raw.c4; break;
        case 5: rId = R.raw.c5; break;
        case 6: rId = R.raw.c6; break;
        case 7: rId = R.raw.c7; break;
        case 8: rId = R.raw.c8; break;
        case 9: rId = R.raw.c9; break;
        case 10: rId = R.raw.c10; break;
        case 11: rId = R.raw.c11; break;
        case 12: rId = R.raw.c12; break;
        case 13: rId = R.raw.c13; break;
        case 14: rId = R.raw.v14; break;
        case 15: rId = R.raw.v15; break;
        case 16: rId = R.raw.v16; break;
        case 17: rId = R.raw.v17; break;
        case 18: rId = R.raw.v18; break;
        case 19: rId = R.raw.v19; break;
        case 20: rId = R.raw.v20; break;
        case 21: rId = R.raw.v21; break;
        case 22: rId = R.raw.v22; break;
        case 23: rId = R.raw.v23; break;

        default: rId = R.raw.error; break;
    }

    soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, rId);
    if (soundPlayer != null){
        soundPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code that uses `MediaPlayer`. Without it it's hard to help.

Comment: It's not complicated or anything, but it's being cut off.

Comment: I'd test on a real device before believing emulators

Comment: I don't have a real device that runs 2.2. If anyone would like to give it a shot, for me I could provide a link if that's allowed on SO?

Comment: How long are these sounds exactly? Would "80%" have around 0.5sec left of play time?

Comment: These are very short clips around 2 seconds or so.

Comment: Late to the party, but the constructor notes sheds some light: **Default constructor. Consider using one of the create() methods for synchronously instantiating a MediaPlayer from a Uri or resource.** This looks to me that after using create, the player should be usable instantly due to the synchronicity. If this is not the case, the docs are faulty, the OS is faulty, or the devices are faulty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters, I would try to make sure `MediaPlayer.create()` function is called prior to the `start()`. If it's a game, load the sounds when they start a new game (creating a new media player for each sound). The reason why is because the `create` function will effectively load the sound file there and then, ready for smooth playback when you call `start`. If you load the file every time before running it, not only are you doing more work than you need to, but it may have undesired effects on the emulator. I'm not sure if you've noticed, but the emulator isn't exact the quickest tool out the shed compared to virtually any actual physical device. As a result, what I think may be happening is the emulator is 'playing' the sound and thinks that it is complete before the sound actually plays, mainly due to the emulator's slow speed.

Try it out on an actual device and I think you won't have any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help. Do you recommend a SoundPool over an array of MediaPlayer objects?

Comment: It depends. Technically speaking, neither is better than the other. Generally speaking, MediaPlayer is used for longer sounds (think background music) and SoundPool is used for sound effects (clicks, guns firing, etc). There are also some technical limitations to each type. MediaPlayer grants the ability to see if a sound is playing, whereas SoundPool does not. However, SoundPool makes it easy to set a max# of sounds and allows the same sound (loaded once) to be played multiple times simultaneously, which MediaPlayer can't do unless you make lots of MediaPlayers of the same sound.

Comment: I recently ran against the same problem but on a real device. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667840/mediaplayer-finishes-playback-earlier-than-it-should
However the issue is only reproduced by an increased speed.

Answer (score 5):

Just discovered this question after having the same problem. The simple answer in my case was to make `MediaPlayer` a class variable. If you make it local to your method the garbage collector apparently sweeps it up and kills the sound play.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a release before to start ... example

```
    if( mPlayer!= null ) mPlayer.release();

     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, listaMP3[contador]);
     mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks-- I did the release at the top of the method. It still causes the cut-off though.

Answer (score 0):

for soem reason if I define the mediaPlayer outside of the method I use to play a song, it works.

Even though I only call the playSong() method once;

```
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.overworld);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(musicVolume, musicVolume);

  playSong();
```

playSong Method:

```
   private void playSong() {

    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
}
```

Comment: I got the same behavior. My guess is that since `start()` does not block, the method exits and the MediaPlayer reference gets destroyed and perhaps the object gets picked up by the GC. Anyone can comment on my guess?